# PowerBI SUMMARIZE with 2 columns

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

So, having issues:

To create the table with 2 columns using summarize, can't figure out how to get the 2nd column. So far I have:

```
=SUMMARIZE(table1,table1[column])
```

Which is fine for the first column. How can I add to this to make the 2nd column to be the same as the first column with padding to make 6 characters in length?

```
COLUMN 1        COLUMN 2
14325           014325
22              000022    
415263          415263    
ABC             000ABC
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pad text with zeros? That doesn't have anything to do with `SUMMARIZE`.

Comment: Yes - didnt know if I could add a column to do that with the summarize function. Or, after creating a one column table with COLUMN 1, could I then create a new column in that table that would then do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to include a second column within `SUMMARIZE` like this:

```
= SUMMARIZE( table1, table1[column], "COLUMN 2", <DAX Expression> )
```

Another way is to do this:

```
= ADDCOLUMNS( SUMMARIZE( table1, table1[column]), "COLUMN 2", <DAX Expression> )
```

---

For padding-left with zeros, try something like this:

```
Summary =
VAR Length = MAXX ( table1, LEN ( table1[column] ) )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE (
        table1,
        table1[column],
        "COLUMN 2", REPT ( "0", Length - LEN ( table1[column] ) ) & table1[column]
    )
```

This prepends as many zeros as necessary to make the string the same length as the longest one in `table[column]`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.